# data transformation for sequence data in R: concatenating data of one column based other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation

I have a dataframe with the long list of sequential actions regarding session number. I want to concatenate all sequential actions in one row in the given session and user_id.
let's say I have:

```
DF:
user_id  session action
1000         1    A
1000         1    B
1000         1    C
1000         2    A
1000         2    B
1001         1    A
1001         1    D
1001         2    B
1001         3    C
1002         1    B
1002         1    D
1002         1    D
```

I want to convert to this format:

```
new_DF:

user_id  session action1 action2 action3
1000       1       A      B       C
1000       2       A      B       NA
1001       1       A      D       NA
1001       2       B      NA      NA
1001       3       C      NA      NA
1002       1       B      D       D
```

the number of columns in new_DF is equal to the maximum number of the actions in a single session. those users with fewer actions receive `NA` for void actions in the session.
How can I do it in R?

Comment: Trying to find a duplicate, but this is a 'long to wide reshape' using user_id and session as the id variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(DF), user_id + session ~ 
      paste0("action", rowid(user_id, session)), value.var = "action")
#      user_id session action1 action2 action3
#1:    1000       1       A       B       C
#2:    1000       2       A       B      NA
#3:    1001       1       A       D      NA
#4:    1001       2       B      NA      NA
#5:    1001       3       C      NA      NA
#6:    1002       1       B       D       D
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    group_by(user_id, session) %>%
    mutate(n = paste0("action", 1:n())) %>%
    spread(n, action)
## A tibble: 6 x 5
## Groups:   user_id, session [6]
#  user_id session action1 action2 action3
#    <int>   <int> <fct>   <fct>   <fct>
#1    1000       1 A       B       C
#2    1000       2 A       B       NA
#3    1001       1 A       D       NA
#4    1001       2 B       NA      NA
#5    1001       3 C       NA      NA
#6    1002       1 B       D       D
```

We group by `user_id` and `session`, then number rows within every group and `spread` to wide.